# if/else to call the function, the rest of the logic is identical

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am having a js code inside a js function.
This contains an `if else` condition which contains same functionality, the only thing changed is the parameter.

So the only thing different is the parameter string you are passing to the functions.
The  if/else is used to call the function, the rest of the logic is identical.

Is it possible to call the function, the rest of the logic is identical?

```
return $(this).each(function () {
                if (coffeeId == "showCoffeeId") {
                    var todayDate = NoteWorklist.getDateTime("appleTime");
                    value.Year = todayDate.getFullYear();
                    value.Month = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
                    value.Day = todayDate.getDate();
                    value.today = todayDate;
                    value.inputDate = todayDate;
                } else {
                    var todayDate = NoteWorklist.getDateTime("orangeTime");
                    value.Year = todayDate.getFullYear();
                    value.Month = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
                    value.Day = todayDate.getDate();
                    value.today = todayDate;
                    value.inputDate = todayDate;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the ternary operator:

```
return $(this).each(function () {
       var todayDate = NoteWorklist.getDateTime(coffeeID == "showCoffeeId" ? "appleTime" : "orangeTime");
       value.Year = todayDate.getFullYear();
       value.Month = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
       value.Day = todayDate.getDate();
       value.today = todayDate;
       value.inputDate = todayDate;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can:

```
return $(this).each(function () {

    var todayDate = NoteWorklist.getDateTime(coffeeId == "showCoffeeId" ? "appleTime" : "orangeTime");
    value.Year = todayDate.getFullYear();
    value.Month = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
    value.Day = todayDate.getDate();
    value.today = todayDate;
    value.inputDate = todayDate;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (coffeeId == "showCoffeeId") {
       var todayDate = NoteWorklist.getDateTime("appleTime");
    } else {
      var todayDate = NoteWorklist.getDateTime("orangeTime");
    }

    value.Year = todayDate.getFullYear();
    value.Month = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
    value.Day = todayDate.getDate();
    value.today = todayDate;
    value.inputDate = todayDate;
```

Comment: @JTorres, inside a function var can be declared anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
return $(this).each(function () {
      var word =""
      if (coffeeId == "showCoffeeId") {
           word = "appleTime";
      } else {
           word = "orangeTime";
      }
     var todayDate = NoteWorklist.getDateTime(word);
     value.Year = todayDate.getFullYear();
     value.Month = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
     value.Day = todayDate.getDate();
     value.today = todayDate;
     value.inputDate = todayDate;
});
```